# alpha parameter in ridge regression is high

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using the Ridge linear regression from sickit learn. In the documentation they stated that the alpha parameter has to be small.

However I am getting my best model performance at 6060. Am I doing something wrong ?

Here is the description from documentation:

```
alpha : {float, array-like} shape = [n_targets] Small positive values
of alpha improve the conditioning of the problem and reduce the
variance of the estimates.
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import custom_metrics as cmetric
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import linear_model

# Read data files:
df_train = pd.read_csv(path + "/input/train.csv")
df_test  = pd.read_csv(path + "/input/test.csv")

#print df.shape
#(50999, 34)

#convert categorical features into integers
feature_cols_obj = [col for col in df_train.columns if df_train[col].dtypes == 'object']
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for col in feature_cols_obj:
    df_train[col] = le.fit_transform(df_train[col])
    df_test[col] = le.transform(df_test[col])

#Scale the data so that each feature has zero mean and unit std
feature_cols = [col for col in df_train.columns if col not in ['Hazard','Id']]
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(df_train[feature_cols])
df_train[feature_cols] = scaler.transform(df_train[feature_cols])                               
df_test[feature_cols] = scaler.transform(df_test[feature_cols]) 

#polynomial features/interactions
X_train = df_train[feature_cols]
X_test = df_test[feature_cols]
y = df_train['Hazard']
test_ids = df_test['Id']
poly = preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures(2)
X_train = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = poly.fit_transform(X_test)

#do grid search to find best value for alpha
#alphas = np.arange(-10,3,1)        
#clf = linear_model.RidgeCV(10**alphas)
alphas = np.arange(100,10000,10)        
clf = linear_model.RidgeCV(alphas)
clf.fit(X_train, y)
print clf.alpha_  
#clf.alpha=6060

cv = cross_validation.KFold(df_train.shape[0], n_folds=10)
mse = []
mse_train = []
fold_count = 0
for train, test in cv:
    print("Processing fold %s" % fold_count)
    train_fold = df_train.ix[train]
    test_fold = df_train.ix[test]

    # Get training examples
    X_train = train_fold[feature_cols]
    y = train_fold['Hazard']
    X_test = test_fold[feature_cols]
    #interactions
    poly = preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures(2)
    X_train = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = poly.fit_transform(X_test)

    # Fit Ridge linear regression 
    cfr = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = 6060)
    cfr.fit(X_train, y)

    # Check error on test set
    pred = cfr.predict(X_test)

    mse.append(cmetric.normalized_gini(test_fold.Hazard, pred))

    # Check error on training set (Resubsitution error)
    mse_train.append(cmetric.normalized_gini(y, cfr.predict(X_train)))    

    # Done with the fold
    fold_count += 1

    #print model coeff

print cfr.coef_

print pd.DataFrame(mse).mean()
#0.311794
print pd.DataFrame(mse_train).mean()
#.344775
```

this is statistical description of one set of the data:
before polynomials features:

```
              T1_V1         T1_V2         T1_V3         T1_V4         T1_V5  \
count  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000   
mean      -0.000731     -0.001736      0.000183     -0.001917      0.000392   
std        1.000116      0.999538      1.000170      1.000554      0.999491   
min       -1.687746     -1.893892     -1.256792     -1.394844     -1.330461   
25%       -0.720234     -0.934764     -0.681865     -0.978753     -1.008006   
50%       -0.139727      0.184219     -0.106938      0.685608      0.281812   
75%        0.827786      0.823638      0.467988      0.685608      1.249175   
max        1.795298      1.782766      3.342622      1.517788      1.571630   

              T1_V6         T1_V7         T1_V8         T1_V9        T1_V10  \
count  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000   
mean       0.000085      0.000574     -0.000776      0.001024     -0.000792   
std        1.000021      1.001709      0.999421      0.999460      0.999491   
min       -0.886738     -2.559151     -2.426625     -2.894427     -1.396415   
25%       -0.886738     -0.188322     -0.199566     -0.499280     -1.118270   
50%       -0.886738     -0.188322     -0.199566     -0.499280      0.272457   
75%        1.127729     -0.188322     -0.199566      0.698293      0.272457   
max        1.127729      4.553336      4.254553      3.093439      1.385038   

           ...              T2_V6         T2_V7         T2_V8         T2_V9  \
count      ...       45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000   
mean       ...          -0.000248     -0.002250      0.002158     -0.002376   
std        ...           1.000600      1.000546      1.009264      1.000567   
min        ...          -1.185107     -1.969111     -0.164560     -1.571220   
25%        ...           0.064723     -0.426425     -0.164560     -0.887667   
50%        ...           0.064723      0.087804     -0.164560      0.206019   
75%        ...           0.064723      1.116261     -0.164560      0.752862   
max        ...           6.313873      1.116261     10.045186      1.709837   

             T2_V10        T2_V11        T2_V12        T2_V13        T2_V14  \
count  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000   
mean      -0.000526     -0.003068      0.000881     -0.003165     -0.000713   
std        0.999744      1.001545      1.000736      1.001126      0.999412   
min       -1.843477     -1.620956     -0.472133     -1.756894     -1.151631   
25%       -0.789013     -1.620956     -0.472133     -0.488816     -0.358019   
50%       -0.261781      0.616920     -0.472133      0.779261     -0.358019   
75%        0.792683      0.616920     -0.472133      0.779261      0.435593   
max        1.319915      0.616920      2.118047      0.779261      3.610041   

             T2_V15  
count  45899.000000  
mean      -0.001722  
std        0.998565  
min       -0.807511  
25%       -0.807511  
50%       -0.482489  
75%        0.492577  
max        2.767731  

[8 rows x 32 columns]
```

after polynomial features:

```
         0             1             2             3             4    \
count  45899  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000   
mean       1     -0.000731     -0.001736      0.000183     -0.001917   
std        0      1.000116      0.999538      1.000170      1.000554   
min        1     -1.687746     -1.893892     -1.256792     -1.394844   
25%        1     -0.720234     -0.934764     -0.681865     -0.978753   
50%        1     -0.139727      0.184219     -0.106938      0.685608   
75%        1      0.827786      0.823638      0.467988      0.685608   
max        1      1.795298      1.782766      3.342622      1.517788   

                5             6             7             8             9    \
count  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000   
mean       0.000392      0.000085      0.000574     -0.000776      0.001024   
std        0.999491      1.000021      1.001709      0.999421      0.999460   
min       -1.330461     -0.886738     -2.559151     -2.426625     -2.894427   
25%       -1.008006     -0.886738     -0.188322     -0.199566     -0.499280   
50%        0.281812     -0.886738     -0.188322     -0.199566     -0.499280   
75%        1.249175      1.127729     -0.188322     -0.199566      0.698293   
max        1.571630      1.127729      4.553336      4.254553      3.093439   

           ...                551           552           553           554  \
count      ...       45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000   
mean       ...           1.001451      0.231269      0.019758     -0.015785   
std        ...           1.647125      0.796845      1.026707      0.910075   
min        ...           0.222910     -3.721184     -2.439209     -1.710345   
25%        ...           0.222910     -0.367915     -0.580348     -0.386016   
50%        ...           0.222910     -0.068564      0.169033      0.227799   
75%        ...           0.222910      0.829488      0.169033      0.381252   
max        ...           4.486123      1.650512      7.646235      5.862185   

                555           556           557           558           559  \
count  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000  45899.000000   
mean       1.002242     -0.072864      0.006086      0.998802     -0.013314   
std        1.070157      1.007916      0.953547      1.768235      0.949678   
min        0.021090     -6.342458     -4.862610      0.128178     -3.187406   
25%        0.607248     -0.278991     -0.629262      0.128178     -0.351746   
50%        0.607248     -0.278991     -0.117269      0.189741      0.072986   
75%        0.607248      0.339440      0.394724      1.326255      0.289104   
max        3.086676      2.813165      2.156786     13.032392      9.991622   

                560  
count  45899.000000  
mean       0.997114  
std        1.573975  
min        0.024796  
25%        0.232795  
50%        0.652073  
75%        0.652073  
max        7.660336
```

This is is the cv_values for alpha:

```
clf = linear_model.RidgeCV(store_cv_values =True)
clf.fit(X_train, y)
print clf.cv_values_  
[[  2.66305438e+00   2.66309171e+00   2.66347365e+00]
 [  1.54423791e+00   1.54415884e+00   1.54339859e+00]
 [  6.67823810e+00   6.67822709e+00   6.67821319e+00]
 ..., 
 [  1.30064559e-02   1.30216638e-02   1.31734569e-02]
 [  2.75705381e+01   2.75705980e+01   2.75713343e+01]
 [  9.88136940e+00   9.88182038e+00   9.88626893e+00]]
```

Comment: What are the feature ranges (min and max) before and after polynomial transform? And can you show the cross-validated scores for the default range alpha?

Comment: @AndreasMueller I have included the info. thanks

Comment: I was asking for the scores when just running RidgeCV with the default alpha. The feature ranges look reasonable.

Comment: @AndreasMuelle I edited my question to include the scores when just running RidgeCV.

Comment: the third to last row shows an RMSE of 1.31734569e-02, that seems pretty good.

Comment: @AndreasMuelle so using a large alpha was fine for me?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a sign of [overfitting](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html); you may want to reduce your feature set.

When fitting the regressor to your training set, some of the features are being used to fit the random variation within the feature set. When tested out-of-sample (e.g. via your k-fold validation) the fit quality will be poor because the extra features are fitting noise rather than central tendencies. A higher `alpha` value helps drive these coefficients to zero, reducing the degree of overfitting.

You may want to prune your feature set (eliminate some of the columns in your input data), perhaps by starting with just the terms which are being heavily weighted by the ridge algorithm.  Another option is to use the `lasso` regressor, which will drive small coefficients to zero. However, the lasso algorithm is not a perfect solution, as it is also susceptible to overfitting.